# ZSH: Where to place environment variable so that launched application can pick it up?

Tags: command-line, shell, zsh, environment-variables, launcher

I need an environment variable `KEY="value"` made available to a GUI application before starting it. The launcher file (the one that places the icon on the desktop and sidebar in Ubuntu) has a value of `Exec=/path/to/executable/file`.

When using ZSH, where should I define this variable so that it is available to that application whether I click the application launcher or whether I directly type /path/to/executable/file in my shell?

In my command line prompt, I tried typing both `KEY="value"` and `export KEY="value"` before clicking the launcher, but it didn't seem to work. I also tried both of those lines in my `~/.zshrc`, did a `source ~/.zshrc` from my shell then clicked the launcher again, but that also didn't work.

Which file should it go in? I believe have a choice of `~/.zshenv`, `~/.zprofile`, `~/.zshrc`, and `~/.zlogin`.

(For bonus points, should I use `export` or not?)

(Am I required to at least log out and log back in, before the variable becomes available to the application when it's launched from the launcher?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you want the variable to be defined as well in your terminal shells (*interactive non-login shell*) and for the desktop launcher icons (X-server started by *non-interactive login shell*) you should put the definition in your `~/.zshenv`.

And yes, you have to restart your x-session in order to have the new environment available for your desktop icons. Imagine such a startup scheme: `Graphical Login -> Use your default shell to start the X session -> Desktop -> Shell terminal / Launch program via icon`, so the child shells inherit the environment from the parent, which is used to start the X session. That shell read the RC-files only once -- on your login to the X session.

For the *bonus point*. This is what the manual says:

> `export [ name[=value] ... ]`
>                 The specified names are marked for automatic export to the environment of subsequently executed commands. (...)

If you define your variable in `~/.zshenv`, you can in principle omit the `export` as this file is read in by default. The only difference arises if you start a shell with `zsh -f`, which sources no RC files. A little demonstration:

```
% foo=foo_defined
% export bar=bar_defined
% print -l $foo $bar
foo_defined
bar_defined
% zsh -f
% print -l $foo $bar
bar_defined
%
```

I. e. only the exported `$bar` is defined in subsequent shells. But to be on the safe side, use `export` -- I can't think of a case where this is harmful.

Comment: By default shell do you mean the one in /etc/passwd? Let's say someone uses bash as their default shell but has gnome-terminal configured to automatically open up in ZSH. In that case will .zshenv be read on startup? If not, is there a shell-independent file that can be used to place variables like this? (I know there's things like ~/.profile and ~/.pam_environment described at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables, but how do those fit in with your answer of ~/.zshenv?)

Comment: @user779159 : Yes, by _default shell_ I meant that one defined in `/etc/passwd`. `zshenv` is `zsh` specific, so is not read in by `bash`, `csh` or whatsoever. My answer applied only to `zsh`, according to your question tag. In an inhomogeneous setup (default shell other that gnome-terminal shell), the possibilities in your link seem sensible. I would put the variable in `~/.profile` and made `zsh` in gnome-terminal a _login shell_ by using `zsh -l` as startup command.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that @mpy is correct that you can omit the export statement. The presence/absence of export determines whether or not processes launched from that shell will inherit the environment variable. If you don't export, xserver will not inherit the environment variable

```
 imalison  ~  ABCD='14'
 imalison  ~  python -c "import os; print os.environ.get('ABCD')"
None
 imalison  ~  export ABCD='14'
 imalison  ~  python -c "import os; print os.environ.get('ABCD')"
14
```

Comment: You're right, normally if you skip `export` then subprocesses won't see the variable. But if you're modifying a variable like `PATH` that has already been exported, so you don't need `export`.

Comment: thank you for this @imalison, as this was the straw that fixed the camel's back ;) lol